# UI not properly updating after moving element from List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

I have a `List<Entry> mySet`, which is a List of widget `Entry`.

In a parent widget, I use a ListView.builder to generate these widgets.

This parent widget has two additional methods

```
addEntry() {
  setState(() {
    mySet.add(Entry(index: mySet.length));
  });
}

removeEntry(_EntryState entry) {
  int index = entry.widget.index;
  setState(() {
    mySet.removeWhere((item) => item.index == index);
  });
}
```

The buttons that call these in each entry look like this

```
IconButton(
  iconSize: 25,
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: index == mySet.last.index
      ? () {
          setState(() {
            pKey.currentState!.addEntry();
          });
        }
      : null),
IconButton(
  iconSize: 25,
  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
  onPressed: isLast(() {
    setState(() {
      pKey.currentState!.removeEntry(this);
    });
  })),
```

And this function

```
isLast(Function fn) => index == mySet.last.index ? fn : null;
```

The condition on the add and subtract functions are identical, this was just me testing and trying to debug the problem.

The problem:

When I click to add a row widget, the prior rows' add/remove buttons are disabled, as they should be.

[image]

But when I click remove on the last row, the prior row's buttons are not re-enabled.

[image]

Yet if I make a small change to the code (anything), to trigger a hot-reload, the last row's buttons enable.

Here's my Listview.builder code, in the same parent widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return mySet[index];
        },
        itemCount: mySet.length);
  }
```

Comment: Do you use UniqueKey ? Have a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: @Kantine Thank you, but unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: The problem likely is in the generation of the ListView within a build function.

Comment: @Ber Though it's very simple, I added my build function to the bottom of the post. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. However, I think whatever you are really trying to do, you have created an overly complex attempt to solve it. My recommendation is to study proper app state management architectures and you an appropriate one. You will typically use a Stream and StreamBuilder to update you page.
For state management:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user in question [Flutter: The widget values ​inside the ListView are not updated when an item is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240713/flutter-the-widget-values-inside-the-listview-are-not-updated-when-an-item-is) has a similar problem.

In your case you can solve this issue by using a `ValueKey(property)` where `property` is a a ofttribute your `Entry` object which you are sure is different for every `Entry`.

Make sure no two Entries can have the same value for `property` at the same time as otherwise flutter will throw an Error as you will have two identical `ValueKeys`.

Comment: ValueKey and UniqueKey are having no effect.

Comment: Are the Entry widgets?

Comment: This did work. I was overriding `key` for some reason, which broke it's internal mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the problem by having one array that tracked instances of Entry, and one array to track corresponding states.

I could then call setState() for the last item which was the source of my trouble in my post.

```
removeEntry(_Entry entry) {
  theSetStates.removeWhere((v) => v == entry);
  theSet.removeWhere((v) => v == entry.widget);
  setState(() {});
  theSetStates.last.setState(() {});
}
```

If there's an easier way to get a list of instances of a Widget. Please let me know. Google didn't turn up anything.